# PHP PDO Undefined Index

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo, indexing, undefined

I've had a look round on google and a couple of other sites, but I can't figure out why this isn't working.

I'm working on a uni assignment, and run the following code:

```
$db = connect();
$testname = 'chunk';
 try {
        $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM TreasureHunt.Player WHERE name = ?');
        $stmt->execute(array($testname));
        $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $stmt->closeCursor();
        } 
    catch (PDOException $e) { 
    print "Error checking login: " . $e->getMessage(); 
}

$count = $stmt->rowCount();
echo 'Row count: ', $count, '<br>';
var_dump($result);
echo '<br>Result: ', $result['name'], ' pw: ', $result["password"], '<br>';
print_r($result);
```

However this results in the following errorm:

```
Notice: Undefined index: name in /.automount/net/ufiler2/u2/cs3/dbes2376/lib/html/th/index.php on line 30
```

Now I know that means, that in my $result variable the index 'name' must not exist. But this confuses me because it does exist, checked by looking in: var_dump($result) 
var_dump($result) gives me:

```
array(1) { [0]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(5) "chunk" ["password"]=> string(7) "truffle" ["pw_salt"]=> string(8) "g#m#g#m#" ["gender"]=> string(1) "m" ["addr"]=> string(10) "Goon Docks" } }
```

and print_r($result) gives me:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => chunk [password] => truffle [pw_salt] => g#m#g#m# [gender] => m [addr] => Goon Docks ) )
```

So why can I not refer to them as $result['name'] ? Or how do I actually refer to it?

Thanks. Sorry if this is a basic question.

Comment: As you can see from the output of `var_dump($result)` , it's an array with another array in it.

Comment: Wow, that's a lot of unexplained downvotes, especially for a question that's actually fairly well written. Downvoters, kindly comment too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using `$result[0]['name'];`

Comment: a little explanation wouldn't hurt, if it would help other users with the same problem..

Comment: Agreed, I will post more information in future.

Answer (score 2):

[`fetchAll()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) returns an array of arrays. So in your case access

```
$result[0]['name']
```

instead of

```
$result['name']
```

Another option would be to use just [`fetch()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) in order to get only the one row of the result each time.

Comment: Ahh.. so its a multidimensional array. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have several errors in your code. I have rewritten it to hopefully remove them, and get it working as expected:

```
$db = connect();
$testname = 'chunk';

try {
    $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM TreasureHunt.Player WHERE name = ?');
    $stmt->execute(array($testname));

    foreach($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row){
        echo 'Result: ' . $result['name'] . ' pw: ' . $result['password'] . '<br />';
    }
} catch (PDOException $e) { 
    print "Error checking login: " . $e->getMessage(); 
}

$count = $stmt->rowCount();
echo 'Row count: ' . $count .  '<br>';
```

Comment: -1 for using exception to print error out... and still many errors left

Comment: @YourCommonSense I only added the exception error because it was in the original code example. Not really a reason for downvoting.

Comment: @YourCommonSense ah, just seen the mistakes with the last echo, corrected them, thanks

Comment: It weren't a mistake but rather correct syntax :)

Answer (score 0):

You have several errors in your code. I have rewritten it to hopefully remove them, and get it working as expected. You have to also connect as described in the [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info)

```
$db = connect();
$testname = 'chunk';
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM TreasureHunt.Player WHERE name = ?');
$stmt->execute(array($testname));
$row = $stmt->fetch();

$count = $stmt->rowCount();
echo 'Row count: ', $count, '<br>';
echo '<br>Result: ', $row['name'], ' pw: ', $row["password"], '<br>';
```